# Physical storage devices, such as tape and changer devices, not visible when booting Debian 8 Jessie, with hpsa driver.

Tags: backup, hp, hp-smart-array, data-recovery, autoloader

**Question**

**Not detecting all physical devices behind Smart Array controller after upgrading to Debian 8 Jessie**

**HP P212 Smart Array Controller and HP 1/8 G2 LTO-5 3000 SAS Autoloader**

*Debian 7 Whezzy kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64:*

```
# lsscsi -g
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD5003ABYX-0 01.0  /dev/sda   /dev/sg0 
[0:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      ST3000DM001-9YN1 CC4B  /dev/sdb   /dev/sg1 
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD30EFRX-68E 80.0  /dev/sdc   /dev/sg2 
[4:0:0:0]    storage HP       P212             5.14  -          /dev/sg3 
[4:2:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   Z58W  /dev/st0   /dev/sg4  <<= physical device (tape)
[4:2:0:1]    mediumx HP       1x8 G2 AUTOLDR   3.50  /dev/sch0  /dev/sg5 <<= physical device (changer), missing in Debian 8
```

*Debian 8 Jessie kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64:*

```
# lsscsi -g
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD5003ABYX-0 01.0  /dev/sda   /dev/sg0 
[0:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      ST3000DM001-9YN1 CC4B  /dev/sdb   /dev/sg1 
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD30EFRX-68E 80.0  /dev/sdc   /dev/sg2 
[4:0:0:0]    storage HP       P212             5.14  -          /dev/sg3 
[4:2:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   Z58W  /dev/st0   /dev/sg4
```

- Missing devices are not detected even after a scsi bus rescan.
- Tape changer missing after moving to Debian 8.

Comment: Missing module available in the last kernel ? Check the logs at the startup to see if there is an error.

Comment: There is no visible error. In wheezy is loading the tape changer module, but not in jessie.
I have seen that in Red Hat when upgrading to 6.6 or 7.1 also happens.

Comment: Do you try to load manually the module ? There is maybe an error.

Comment: The solution was to install Debian Jessie, where the robot that moves the tape is not detected, and then add the repository of Debian Testing (Stretch), install kernel 4.5.0-1-amd64 Debian 9 and then restart, detects again the robot moves the tape. Thanks for your supports!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are have following hardware

- HP StoreEver 1/8 G2 LTO-6 Ultrium 6250 Tape Autoloader

With the original Jessie Kernel 3.16.0-4 the autoloader is not found.

Adding the kernel from backports (jessie-backports) is sufficient.

```
uname -a
Linux backup2 4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.3-1~bpo8+1 (2016-07-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and now the autoloader shows up

```
[0:0:0:0]    storage HP       P440ar           3.56  -          /dev/sg0 
[0:1:0:0]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   3.56  /dev/sda   /dev/sg1 
[0:1:0:1]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   3.56  /dev/sdb   /dev/sg2 
[1:0:0:0]    storage HP       H241             3.00  -          /dev/sg3 
[1:0:1:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 6-SCSI   35GW  /dev/st0   /dev/sg4 
[1:0:2:0]    mediumx HP       1x8 G2 AUTOLDR   4.40  /dev/sch0  /dev/sg5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is your case, but i was having a problem with a TL4000 on Ubuntu 16.04. The autoloader was showing when using `lsscsi -g` but suddenly disappeared.

I just found out that, on the Library Type configuration on the `TL` are two options: Random and Sequential. I've changed it to sequential, thinking that it was going to force the Library to use the tapes in the numbered order.

This option make the changer disappear on the server. I tested change this option back and forth and everytime it is on Sequential the changer disappear.